# Can i get the time in milliseconds when the scheduler started in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

I have a method which will be running at an interval of 2 hrs and is mentioned in cron of Scheduler in Spring boot application.
Now my question is can I get the time in milliseconds when the scheduler ran?

I tried to get the time but not able to fetch it when the scheduler ran.

Comment: You could try to log or capture that otherwise right at the start of the job. That might be off a millisecond or 2 but would still be quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring guide of scheduler give a similar example , see the link : https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ .

You can log the time to a logFile but as Thomas mention the exact time of execution may be after some millisonconds (related with the machine and the thread scheduler and the time needed by the thread to do the task of log or print to the outputStream).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void reportCurrentTime() {
    log.info("The time is now {}", LocalDateTime.now());
    // System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
}
}
```